# Model.eval duration vs model.train

Tags: pytorch

We are experiencing strange behaviour in training and evaluating our model.

Since a while we are trying to optimize our performance, but we encountered as in our mind a strange behaviour.

> To train one epoch we need roughly **70min** with **5400 inputs**. To

> eval the model takes around **55min** on **4600 inputs** .

Does this even makes sense? We have a batch_size of 32. each batch takes around 1.5s to load into memory.

Following our train and eval loop:

I removed logging and timing from code to make it more compact:

Main.py

```
for epoch in range(1, config.general['epochs'] + 1):
    closs = runner.train(train_loader=train_loader,
                         epoch=epoch,
                         log_interval=config.general['log_interval'],
                         batch_size=config.data['batch_size'])
   
    vloss = runner.test(test_loader=test_loader, log_interval=config.general['log_interval'])
    scheduler.step()
```

Runner.py

```
def train(self, train_loader, epoch, log_interval, batch_size):
    self.model.train()
    closs = 0
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        data = data.to(self.device)
        target = target.to(self.device)
        output = self.model(data)['normalized']
        loss = self.loss_function(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        closs = closs + loss.detach().item()
        self.optimizer.step()
    return closs


def test(self, test_loader, log_interval):
    self.model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        correct = 0
        vloss = 0
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
            data = data.to(self.device)
            target = target.to(self.device)
            output = self.model(data)
            loss = self.loss_function(output['normalized'], target)
            vloss = vloss + loss.detach().item()
            pred = output['x'].max(1)[1]  # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target).cpu().sum().item()

        accr = 100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset) accr))
        return vloss
```

Performance measurements:

~7s for those 3 lines in train()

```
        output = self.model(data)['normalized']
        loss = self.loss_function(output, target)
        loss.backward()
```

~20s for those 2 lines test()

```
            loss = self.loss_function(output['normalized'], target)
            vloss = vloss + loss.detach().item()
```

Strange thing also even tough we are using `torch.no_grad()` our GPU-Memory usage is around 90%.

We are now totally not sure if we should invest more time in optimizing our performance or if this is just normal behaviour. Until up now I'm thinking that evaluation should be much faster than training even tough we have roughly the same size as training data(we use only 20% of whole train_set) and test data.

EDIT: Is it normal that evaluation takes as much time as training? My guess no. But i cannot explain the described behaviour

EDIT2: added measures. Those measurments seem to be extremely weird isn't it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking if it's normal for the GPU to be in use even when you wrap your code in `with torch.no_grad()`?

Comment: Added clear question ;) @Seankala

Comment: Is it possible most of your time is I/O?

Comment: have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: I also don't think that it's "normal" for simple evaluation to be taking as long as training, but at the same time it's really hard to make that conclusion; there are just way too many variables that could be affecting speed to tell. In your case, however, I don't think it's that surprising considering that you have roughly similar amounts of training and evaluation data samples.

Comment: I've update my question again with some performance idicators

Comment: Is it even possible to calc the loss in evaluation-mode as this issue describes that it is only possible to calc the loss in train mode https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/issues/178